# SIFR - LINK IN A LIST

Tags: list, sifr, hyperlink, words, cut

I have a problem using sIFR for links in a list.

- When I try to apply it to the  my links are perfectly skinned (with the right font and right color) but the last word of each link is cut or display on an other line.
- When I apply it to the

  the text is well displayed but appears as a hypertextlink (blue and underline).

I have tryed anything like forceWidth: true, fitExactly: true, forceSingleLine: true preventWrap: true Nothing seems to work.

I am totally desesperate right now. Do someone as the same problem ?

I am working with wordpress.

Here is an exemple of the problem :
http://www.thibaudcartigny.com/exemple.jpg

Thks for reading.

Answer (score 2):

The most common reason for this (at least in my dealings with siFR) is that the replaced CSS style that lies "behind" the siFR rendered style is too small. sIFR applies its own style rules, but reserves space for the rendered font according to that underlying style. If the total width of the text in that CSS style is not as wide than the text rendered by SIFR, SIFR assumes it has run out of space and makes a line break.

Try giving that style a larger `letter-spacing` or `padding`. Often, this is caused by a negative  `letter-spacing` that you just need to set back to 0.

Remember, I am not talking about the style you define for the siFR font in the settings file, but the one you are replacing!

Comment: Oh it works perfectly. I just had a letter-spacing:1px; And it works well !!
Thank you so much, I ve been on this for a long time !